# Regex in Google Analytics v4 to fetch pagePath not containing "?"

Tags: python, regex, google-analytics-api

I want to fetch the pagePath dimension which does not contain the symbol `?` in Google Analytics Reporting API v4 Python client.

The problem is, that all the solutions on the internet suggest using `"^((?!\?).)*$"` (a negative lookahead). This solution works fine elsewhere, except the Google Analytics Reporting API. As I'm getting the following error:

`HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://analyticsreporting.googleapis.com/v4/reports:batchGet?alt=json returned "Invalid regular expression: '^((?!\?).)*$'. Regular expressions should follow RE2 syntax.">`

And I'm unable to find a solution to this. Please mention if I'm doing something wrong, and the correct solution if possible.

Comment: If you want to keep the group, try `^([^?]+)$` which matches 1+ times any char except `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pattern `^((?!\?).)*$` uses a negative lookahead which matches any char except a newline when what is directly on the right is not a `?` and that syntax is not supported by [re2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

You might simplify that to using a negated character class matching any char 1+ times (to prevent matching an empty string) except a `?` or a newline.

```
^([^?\r\n]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/evyXKy/1)

If you want the match only you can omit the parenthesis.